# AnyLogic - cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTOE0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Hoe.jpg)

Hello,
Im trying to make a Fire Evacuation Simulation. So i copied the model from Anylogic cloud and i edited it (Here is the link to the model i copied; https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/6b60d89a-2da5-45e8-96d7-8ecfd210f7c5?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL)

But My model has 3 errors. "main cannot be resolved to a variable". i can't fix these errors. Can anyone suggest how i can fix?
i compared java codes in the 2 models and found a difference. The code in the last photo isn't included in my model. But no changes are made to the java screen.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. "I cant fix these errors" is not helpful. Make our lives easy (not yours by just dumping the model here hoping someone will fix it) :) We are all happy to help but very busy as well. Check this overview to the community: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Or break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow